# What is the difference between the driver that comes with Ubuntu and Intel open source graphics driver?

Tags: intel-graphics

What is the difference between the driver that comes with Ubuntu and Intel open source graphics driver?

Installing the Intel driver will improve performance and reduce battery consumption considerably?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what is the difference between the driver that comes with ubuntu and intel open source graphics driver ?

They are the same driver.  The benefit of the one included in Ubuntu is that it will have had an additional period of testing by Ubuntu and its users and will remain stable for the life of that Ubuntu release.  The benefit of obtaining it from Intel directly is that it will be a more recent version.

> installing intel driver will improve performance and reduce battery consumption considerably ?

Unlikely.  It's basically the same driver, the only differences will be as stated above; if it's a more recent version, then battery consumption may have improved, but there's also a small chance that it's worsened or that you may notice other issues.  There's no reason to install the driver from Intel unless dealing with specific problems it may solve.

Answer (score 4):

They are the same. It's just that the one shipped by default by ubuntu are just a little old. But not much.

With the *intel graphic driver installer*, you get the *latest of their latest* driver. if your distro is supported.
As of today, 14.10 is still not. just a few days to wait though.